# Multiple glm in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, glm

I have an R dataframe, strongly simplified as:

```
id <- rep(1:2, c(6,8))
correct <- sample(0:1,14,TRUE)
phase <- c(rep("discr",3),rep("rev",3), rep("discr",4),rep("rev",4))
dat <- data.frame(id,correct,phase)
```

with `id` as my subjects (in reality I have a lot more than 2), `correct` = responses coded as incorrect (0) or correct (1), and the `phases` Discrimination and Reversal (within-subjects factor).

I want to perform a logistic regression in the form of

```
glm(correct~phase, dat, family="binomial")
```

later possibly adding additional predictors. 
However, since I have a varying amount of data for each subject, I would like to perform `glm()` seperately for each subject and later compare the coefficients with ANOVA for group effects. 
I would like to do this in a for loop in the form of

```
for(i in seq_along(dat$id)){
   my_glm[i] <- glm(correct~list,dat[dat$id==i,],family="binomial")
}
```

but keep receiving the error message

```
>Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :
 contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels.
```

I have checked my data and there is no factor which contains only one level. All subjects gave at least one incorrect and one correct response, and all took part in Discrimination and Reversal. The function works outside the loop when I specify a particular subject.

Comment: First problem is that function seq_along(dat$id) produces numbers from 1:14  but you have only 2 levels. You can replace it with seq_along(unique(dat$id)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you currently trying to do a `glm` for each row in of `id`:

I think you want a `glm` for each `id` seperately.  *Personally*, I would go with something like:

```
library(plyr)

ddply(dat, .(id), function (x){
intercept <- coef(summary(glm(correct~phase,family="binomial",data=x)))[1]
slope     <- coef(summary(glm(correct~phase,family="binomial",data=x)))[2]
c(intercept,slope)                 
                              })

# id         V1            V2
#1  1 -0.6931472  1.386294e+00
#2  2  1.0986123 -6.345448e-16

# here V1 is intercept and V2 is the estimate
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you! I was not aware of this package.

Comment: @LucyVanes: based on your question you might want a list of `glm` objects rather than a data frame of coefficients, in which case `dlply` would be more applicable

Comment: You may be right. In any case, both functions are very handy to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here's an R Base solution:

```
> lapply(split(dat, dat$id), function(x) coef(summary(glm(correct~phase,family="binomial",data=x))))
$`1`
                 Estimate Std. Error       z value  Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -6.931472e-01   1.224745 -5.659524e-01 0.5714261
phaserev    -3.845925e-16   1.732050 -2.220446e-16 1.0000000

$`2`
                Estimate Std. Error      z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) 3.356998e-16   1.000000 3.356998e-16 1.000000
phaserev    1.098612e+00   1.527524 7.192109e-01 0.472011
```