# How can I make an object created within ddply available outside the function (in the global environment)?

Tags: r, plyr, glm

I am trying to run glm on a number of individual subjects within a data set to return specific coefficients. I found an example here ([Multiple glm in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483128/multiple-glm-in-for-loop?answertab=active#tab-top)) that works really well. Except, the result prints to the screen but is not available afterwards. So, I can't save the result or rename the variables unless I highlight the screen in RStudio then copy/paste into Excel.

Data:

```
   Subject SNRs Prop_Correct Ntrials
       1    3         0.65     100
       1    0         0.40     100
       1   -3         0.15     100
       1   -6         0.00     100
       1   -9         0.00     100
       1  -12         0.00     100
       2    3         0.65     100
       2    0         0.40     100
       2   -3         0.15     100
       2   -6         0.00     100
       2   -9         0.00     100
       2  -12         0.00     100
       3    3         0.65     100
       3    0         0.40     100
       3   -3         0.15     100
       3   -6         0.00     100
       3   -9         0.00     100
       3  -12         0.00     100
```

My script:

```
ddply(Data, .(Subject), function (x){
  intercept <- coef(summary(glm(Prop_Correct~SNRs, weights=Ntrials,family=quasibinomial(link='logit'),data=x)))[1]
  slope     <- coef(summary(glm(Prop_Correct~SNRs, weights=Ntrials,family=quasibinomial(link='logit'),data=x)))[2]
  SNR50      <- (log(0.5/(1-0.5))/slope) - (intercept/slope)
  Data_Summary <- c(SNR50,slope)
})
```

Which gives me this output:

```
  Subject       V1        V2
1       1 1.266165 0.4834356
2       2 1.266165 0.4834356
3       3 1.266165 0.4834356
```

However:

```
Data_Summary
Error: object 'Data_Summary' not found
```

How can I make the result of the ddply function available to the main/global environment?

Comment: You need to assign the result of your function to the name Data_Summary in the globalenv(), not in the function.

Comment: That's the problem I can't solve. The results of the function aren't available outside the function. 

If I try Data_Summary after the function, I get:
Error: object 'SNR50' not found

Comment: try `assign` function.

Comment: That almost works, except I only get the results of the last subject.


 `results <- c(slope,SNR50)`
  `assign("Data_Summary",value=results,envir=globalenv())`
  
`})`

I get the expected output printed to screen, But Data_Summary only shows 2 values in a single row

Comment: Use `list` rather than `c`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the results to a variable:

```
Data_Summary_df <- ddply(Data, .(Subject), function (x){
  intercept <- coef(summary(glm(Prop_Correct~SNRs, weights=Ntrials,family=quasibinomial(link='logit'),data=x)))[1]
  slope     <- coef(summary(glm(Prop_Correct~SNRs, weights=Ntrials,family=quasibinomial(link='logit'),data=x)))[2]
  SNR50      <- (log(0.5/(1-0.5))/slope) - (intercept/slope)
  Data_Summary <- c(SNR50,slope)
})

Data_Summary_df
```

Though there are a lot of things going on, treat it as you would any function call, if not assigned to a variable, it just outputs the result, if you want the result retained you assign it to a variable, e.g.

```
mean(1:25)
calc_mean <- mean(1:25)
calc_mean
```

Comment: Fantastic and embarrassingly straightforward! Thank you!

Comment: That ... is a close approximation to what my comment recommended. The `Data_Summary <-` inside the function does exactly nothing. The value of Data_Summary only gets assigned with the `Data_Summary_df <-`. Should just have the final line inside the function as `c(SNR50,slope)`.